# How to get grid subchildren items to be inline?

Tags: css

I am trying to understand how the grid system works for creating site or site parts.
So, for example,
if I have:

```css
.container {
  display: grid; 
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  gap: 0px 0px; 
}
```

Now, sub-children are going one after another, and I do not realize why.
Here is an example, see the `item31` list: [Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/nd1s5ota/)

Every item 31 is one under another, and I want it to be inline, I do not understand this, I did not work with grid css until now, just a bit with flex.
I can work this out with Flex, but I am trying to understand the grid style.

Should I use `display: grid;` on children and sub-children elements in a grid system of CSS, or grid system of CSS is used only for something global inside we should put elements like `display: flex; display: block;` and similar.

I tried using Flex, and this work, but I want to know how the grid system works, is it just for a global template for which we should use Flex and other styling inside of a grid system?
So far, this, one under another thing is annoying me.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
}

.i1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0px 0px;
  grid-template-areas: ".";
  justify-content: start;
  align-content: space-around;
  justify-items: start;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: stretch;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Layout</h1>

<p>This grid layout contains 4 columns and 1 rows:</p>

<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="i1">
    <div class="item31">item31</div>
    <div class="item31">item31</div>
    <div class="item31">item31</div>
    <div class="item31">item31</div>
  </div>
  <div class="i2">Menu</div>
  <div class="i3">Main</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the grid display can be complicated. My advice is to play around with a grid-garden. It will help you understand the properties of the grid. https://cssgridgarden.com/